# async each on HTTP PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, http-put

im trying to send multiple http put request to my server, but i only manage to send one JSON to the database, what i am missing here

```
var data1 =  JSON.stringify(require('./abc.json')),
    data2 =  JSON.stringify(require('./abe.json')),
    data3 =  JSON.stringify(require('./abd.json'));

var put_data = [data1,data2,data3];

async.each(put_data, function(data, callback){

    var post_options = {
        hostname: config.serviceHost,
        port    : '80',
        path    : '/API/Nag',
        method  : 'PUT',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': config.secret
        }
    };

    post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ', chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            callback();
        });
    });

    post_req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    post_req.write(data); //posting data
    post_req.end();
}, function(err){
    console.log('All requests done!')
});
```

even tho it send 3 http request, all three request contains same data

Comment: `all three request contains same data` - and which data is that? data1? data2? data3? something else?

Comment: by the way, is `var put_data` ... `async.each(post_data` a typo in the question? or is that your actual code?

Comment: @JaromandaX it was a typo, and one time it will be data1, next time it will be data3 it varies

Answer (score 0):

The variable `post_req` has global scope. Meaning the value of `post_req` can be accessed and modified outside `async.each` function.

The solution is to add one `var` before `post_req` that would restrict the variable scope to async and also spawns a new variable for each iteration.